# flutter android gradle error with flutterdownloader

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have implemented flutterDownloader (its a package for downloading files in flutter ) in my project and when I add it to android manifest like the doc says and when I do that gradle shows this error

**error : **

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/fahmi/mscmu/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 27; columnNumber: 35; The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "provider" is not bound.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

my android manifest->
**Android Manifest :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kivoc99.mscmu">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="mscmu"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            tools:node="remove" />

        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-downloader-init"
            android:exported="false">
            <!-- changes this number to configure the maximum number of concurrent tasks -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
                android:value="5" />
        </provider>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

what is the problem here ? I have tried to do exactly what the docs says , any help ?

Answer (score 5):

you have to bind the tools attribute to your manifest element:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="[YOUR APP NAME]" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
```

Comment: Adding xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" after package{"Your app name"} actually worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it! You need to add this line to the manifest tag it's actually the first tag in the file: `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`